# Parsing xml under node attribute

Tags: python, xml

```
    <Step Id="7" Group="Main" Name="Fruit" StepType="ET_MNLT" Status="Passed" total_time="0" StepIndex="0" StepCausedUUTFailure="false">
      <NumericLimit Name="Banana" NumericValue="3" Units="" CompOperator="LOG" Status="Passed" MeasIndex="0" MeasOrderNumber="24" />
      <NumericLimit Name="Apple" NumericValue="0" Units="" CompOperator="LOG" Status="Passed" MeasIndex="1" MeasOrderNumber="25" />
    </Step>
    <Step Id="8" Group="Main" Name="Fruit per km" StepType="ET_MNLT" Status="Passed" total_time="0" StepIndex="1" StepCausedUUTFailure="false">
      <NumericLimit Name="Banana" NumericValue="2.2" Units="" CompOperator="LOG" Status="Passed" MeasIndex="0" MeasOrderNumber="34" />
      <NumericLimit Name="Apple" NumericValue="0" Units="" CompOperator="LOG" Status="Passed" MeasIndex="1" MeasOrderNumber="35" />
    </Step>
```

I often parse this xml to get all the Name and their NumericValue by using the following code:

```
    for branch in root.findall(f".//{namespace}NumericLimit"):
        parameter = branch.get('Name')
        value = round(float(branch.get('NumericValue')), 3)
```

How would I get just the 'Name' and 'NumericValue' for just Step Id="8"?

I tried this:

```
for branch in root.findall(f"*[@Id='8']//{namespace}NumericLimit")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using beautifulsoup or lxml?

Comment: @JackFleeting xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Comment: It's simpler with lxml, if you can use it.

Comment: @JackFleeting not sure if I can, but how would I do it with lxml?

Answer (score 1):

With lxml, it should be something like this (you'll have to take care of namespaces in your actual xml and of rounding, etc.)

```
import lxml.html #if your actual code is valid xml, you would use from lxml import etree
steps = """[your html above]"""
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(steps) #if you imported etree, you would use etree.XML(steps)
for e in doc.xpath('//step[@id="8"]//numericlimit'):
    print(e.xpath('./@name')[0], e.xpath('./@numericvalue')[0])
```

Output:

```
Banana 2.2
Apple 0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write up this answer for me. Unfortunately, I have too much of my code using xml.etree.ElementTree and looking at what you suggested I don't think I can change it over to the lxml library.

Comment: Maybe something like ... for node in root.findall(f".//{namespace}Step"):
                    if node.attrib['Id'] == "8":
                        print(node.attrib['Name'])?

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """[your data above here]"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

outcome = []
for ent in root.findall(".//step[@id='8']/numericlimit"):
    res = [(k,v) for k,v in ent.attrib.items()
           if k in ('name','numericvalue')]
    outcome.append(dict(res))

print(outcome)


[{'name': 'Banana', 'numericvalue': '2.2'},
 {'name': 'Apple', 'numericvalue': '0'}]
```